# Why is the error "response.status is not function". Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am writing a query controller in pure Node js. Why is the error "response.status is not function" coming to the console?

```
const Admins = require('../models/admins')
const Films = require('../models/films')
const Categories = require('../models/categories')

module.exports =  function requestController(request, response){
    if(request.method === 'GET' && request === '/admins/all'){
        Admins.findAll()
        .then(()=>{
            response.status(200).json()
        })
    }else{
        console.log(response)
        response.status(400).json()
    }
}
```

I tried changing the names and displaying the response in the console. response didn't really have a status function.

the function of creating a server and calling the main-contrller

```
    const db = require('./base');
    const http = require('http');
    const port = 3500;
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const requestController = require('./controllers/main-controller');
    
    http.createServer(function(request, response){
        console.clear();
        console.log('=================================');
        console.log('||     SERVER WORKED           ||');
        console.log('=================================');
        requestController(request,response);
    response.end('Server Ready');
    }).listen(port);
```

Comment: how is your `requestController` function called?

Comment: in app.js const requestController = require('./controllers/main-controller');

Comment: share you route code for this controller

Comment: I've attached the server code if that's what you're thinking

Comment: look at the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener) example usage ... response status for example is done by `res.writeHead` and repsonse itself is sent using `res.end` and "manually" stringifying to send JSON ...[more docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse) -  you seem to think node's builtins work like expressjs ... also, why would you end **every** response by sending `'Server Ready'`?

Comment: `response` doesn't have a method called `status`. Refer the `http` module API documentation of NodeJS, [http.serverResponse](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse). To set the status code you use, for example,  `response.statusCode = 400`. (As a side note, you are copy pasting from some code without verifying the details).

Answer (score 2):

You are using express syntax in native http, so it does not have `status` or `json` functions.
You can use `end`, `writeHead`,`statusCode` instead.

Refer this [DOC](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse)

```js
module.exports =  function requestController(request, response){
    if(request.method === 'GET' && request === '/admins/all'){
        Admins.findAll()
        .then(()=>{
            response.writeHead(200,{
                "content-type":"application/json"
            });
            const data = { /** your data */
                user: "test"
            }
            const result = JSON.stringify(data); /** You have to stringify before sent it to response */
            response.end(result)
        })
    }else{
        console.log(response)
        response.statusCode = 400;
        response.end("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Admins = require('../models/admins');
const Films = require('../models/films');
const Categories = require('../models/categories');
    
module.exports = function requestController(request, response) {
        if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/admins/all') {
            Admins.findAll()
            .then(() => {
              
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            
                response.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Success' }));
            });
        } else {
            console.log(response);
          
            response.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         
            response.end(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Bad Request' }));
        }
 };
```

The error `response.status` is not a function occurs because the response object in the Node.js http module does not have a status method.

Remember, when you're not using a framework like Express.js that abstracts these details away, you need to manually handle HTTP status codes, headers, and response bodies with the native Node.js http module methods.

In this corrected version, I've replaced `response.status(200).json()` with the appropriate method for setting the status code and headers in plain Node.js:

`response.writeHead(statusCode, headers)`: This method sets the response status code and headers. For example, `response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })` sets the status code to 200 and the Content-Type header to `application/json`.

`response.end(data)`: This method sends the response data and signals to the server that all of the response headers and body have been sent. For example, `response.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Success' }))` sends a JSON response.